How can I map (concatenate) two GravityForms fields into a third field … All on the same form?
I have created one Contact Us form using GravityForm 2.8 in WordPress 6.5.
I want the phone and address fields to be masked appropriately for U.S. customers. I don't want to force a U.S. phone mask or zip code mask for international customers.
I've done this by adding THREE address blocks to my form. Highest on the form is the "RealAddress," with only the Country field visible. If the country is the U.S., the USAddress block is visible, and the IntAddress block is hidden. Change the country, and the visibility of the two blocks swap.
From the End User view, this is working exactly like I want.
However … When the user hits the SUBMIT button, ONLY ONE Address can be sent to our CRM.
Since only one of the address blocks will be filled in I thought I would set the value of RealAddress1 to the concatenation of USAddress1 and IntAddress1; RealCity to the concatenation of USCity and IntCity; etc.
How can I dynamically set the value of one field to the Concatenation of two other fields, either as type or after the Submit button is pressed, but before it gets sent to our CRM (SalesForce - Using CRM Perks' SalesForce plugin)?

I believe this should do the trick for you:
https://gravitywiz.com/use-merge-tags-as-dynamic-population-parameters/
If you're looking for something fancier, you could accomplish the same with Populate Anything's Live Merge Tags:
https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/#live-merge-tags
